# How would I solve: $\log_{16} 32 = x$?

Tags: logarithms

How would I solve: $\log_{16} 32 = x$?

What I know:

- 16 is the base
- 32 is the exponent

$$
32 = 16^x
$$

I'm stuck at this point$\ldots$

Comment: Take logarithms to base 2 of your final equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $$32=16^x$$

**Hint:**

$$2^5=2^{4x}$$

**Spoiler:**

> $$4x=5$$
>
>
>  $$\boxed{x=\frac 5 4}$$

Comment: Clear explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Observe that $32 = 16 \cdot 2$, and $16 = 2^4$, so $2 = 16^z$ where $z = $ what?

Comment: i have to say this is more direct than my answer

Answer (score 3):

$32 = 16^x$ is the same as $32 = (2^4)^x = 2^{4x}$ and you know that $32 = 2^5$  and so $32 = 2^\color{red}{5} = 2^{\color{red}{4x}}$and so $\color{red}{4x = 5}$ and hence $$x = \frac{5}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

First, i want to point out that $x=\log_{16}32$ IS a solution, just not a very useful one since you need to convert to base $e$ or base $10$ to use a calculator usually.

Now that you have $16^x=32$, you can use a log of known base (most commonly, natural log) and plug that in to a calculator to find a value.

$\ln(16^x)=\ln32$

$x\ln16=\ln32$

$x=\frac{\ln32}{\ln16}$

Comment: It may be better to use $\lg x \equiv \log_2 x$.

Comment: agreed. i was commenting on your answer right when you said that.

Comment: Ok, but my quiz said the answer was $5/4$

Comment: But in fact, your answer is just as direct, provided one uses $\lg x$.

Comment: Can you please show me how to get to 5/4? All of the possible answers were fractions

Comment: use a calculator. alternatively, solve $2^5=2^{4x}$ by rewriting as $2^5=(2^4)^x$